# Is there a quicker way to batch protect the files?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to edit something like this:

```
Sub password()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim StrPassword As String, strFile As String, strFolder As String

StrPassword = "xxxxxxx"
strFolder = "C:\"
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*Report.xlsx", vbNormal)

FastMode True


While strFile <> ""

   Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=strFolder & strFile)

    With wb
        .password = StrPassword
        .SaveAs filename:=wb.FullName, password:=StrPassword
        .Close
    End With
    strFile = Dir()

Wend

FastMode False

End Sub



Public Sub FastMode(ByVal Toggle As Boolean)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not Toggle
    Application.EnableEvents = Not Toggle
    Application.DisplayAlerts = Not Toggle
    Application.EnableAnimations = Not Toggle
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not Toggle
    Application.PrintCommunication = Not Toggle
    Application.Calculation = IIf(Toggle, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
End Sub
```

I was wondering if there was a way to assign a pathway directory and eliminate the need to open-password protect-close each file? I can tell that the process of that is what takes up 99% of the time it takes to execute the code.

Are there ways to batch-append a password without actually taking that much action to open/close the files individually?

It takes about 20 minutes to password protect 2500 files, which isn't bad, but I'm wondering if it can be done much quicker?

Comment: If your code works and you're looking for feedback on any/all aspects of it and want to ultimately end up with code that's as good as it gets, consider putting it up on [codereview.se], with a description of what it does. I can think of several improvements, but FWIW no, I don't think there's any way around opening and saving-as-with-a-password, since adding a password involves saving-as.

Comment: Adding to @MathieuGuindon 's comment: When a file is saved with a password it's also encrypted. That means the Excel application is required to do the encrypting ("Save As"). For this reason, it's also not possible to use the Open XML file format for password protecting Office files.